# How to know my free disk space on web hosting server?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development

I have got some work from my friend for updating his website. Earlier his website was made by some other person and he used to maintain all the stuff. Now that developer has given only the ftp username and password to my friend. He asks me to update his website. But the problem is I don't know how to access the things for this particular web hosting account like knowing the available free space, accesing email account, etc. I asked him about website control panel but he says that he doesn't know about.

Is there any other site/client program/control panel that I can use to manage that website.

So can any one help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution finally when I was inspecting the files using simple ftp. There was an html file that was pointing to my plesk control panel where I had to use that panel for controlling all the stuff. But thanks all for the answers.

Answer (score 3):

What you'll need access to is either the plesk or cpanel. (Some hosts use plesk some use cpanel.) From there you can fully administer the hosting, set up email addresses, add sub
domains, databases, cron jobs, etc.

Depending who hosts the site you can also get basic access to all of the above features through an admin dashboard, but that differs from hosting to hosting.

Comment: I have seen an index page there where I have seen something about "PARALLE PLESK" so that might be the control panel that I need to use. But when I visited their site it said that the plesk panel is a paid version. Can you point me where I should look for my plesk control panel.

Comment: it all depends on what hosting you are on, some hosting has plesk including some you have to pay extra for it as i think its licensed. If you can tell me the host and hosting package ill be able to tell you

Answer (score 1):

That kind of configuration is only accessible from the control panel since it depends on system configurations, like quotas, real disk space, settings of the virtual host, etc.

Your friend should get that information, or if he has the information of the registry of the domain, just move the site to a new hosting, or a new account in the same hosting company, that way you will have all the required access and informations.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the hoster, it may also be possible that you have an SSH account. If so, you probably could add email accounts, create databases etc. on the terminal.

However, most (shared) hosters offer a web-interface. And in most cases the web-interface account is not the same as the FTP account.

So you'd have to contact the former person for the login data. Or, if the email address of your friend was used, you could reset the password.